# How to control exposure time with camera API in some Android phones

Tags: android, camera, shutter, camera-api, exposure

I use `camera.getParameters()` to get all camera parameters of the smart phone, and `camera.getParameters.set(key, value)` to control the target parameters.

When I choose MX4 as my test phone, the parameters contain two parameters as follows: `shutter-value = 0` and `shutter-value-supported = 0, 125, 250, 500, 1000, ... , 10000000` of millisecond. Then I set the `shutter-value = 125` and take a picture, I find it works.

Let's go on. Then I choose MI6 as my next text phone, not as the same as MX4, the parameters contain three parameters about exposure time as follows: `manual-exposure-modes = off, exp-time-priority, iso-priority, user-seting`, `max-exposure-time = 459.592350`, `min-exposure-time = 0.019681`. It puzzles me a lot that there is not a parameter like `exposure-time-value`. I set 'exposure-time = 100 or 0.1' myself, the camera works but I didn't observe the difference. Then, I set 'exposure-time = 0.01', smaller than 0.019681, the camera didn't work, looks like this parameters did work. But this parameter 'exposure-time' is set by myself.

So, can you give me an answer that how to control the exposure-time with camera API not camera 2 API.

Thanks a lot.